# How to implement scroll on page in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

aboutData['intro'] contains the following html

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#Om" target="_self">Om statistikk.siu.no</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Vilkar" target="_self">Vilkår for bruk</a></li>
</ul>
<p>  
  <a name="Om" id="Om"></a>
  Om statistikk.siu.no Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</p>
<p>
  <a name="Vilkar" id="Vilkar"></a>
  Vilkar Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

On clicking href, the page scrolls to corresponding id element but it gives the error :

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Vilkar'.
```

I cannot define these href routes in the routing config as this html came from database and appended to div element as innerhtml.

```
<div [innerHTML]="aboutData['intro']|safeHtml"></div>
```

The problem is that I want the page to scroll but without hitting routes. Can someone help me with this out?

Comment: You can add wildcard routes that match everything to avoid this error `path: '**', ...`

Comment: This is my page URl: http://localhost:4200/#/source;country=0;county=0;level=0;institution=0. 
If i use {path:'**', redirectTo:'source', pathMatch:'full'} . Then after clicking link it becomes http://localhost:4200/#/source. I want to maintain url as before after clicking link.

Comment: I see. `href="#Om"` seems to conflict with HashLocationStrategy. Can you try with default (PathLocationStrategy)?

Comment: How can I migrate to path location strategy as my whole application is developed on hashlocationstrategy

Comment: If the whole application is Angular, then you just need to remove the `LocationStrategy` provider or `useHash: true` (depending on how you enabled it). You need to ensure the used server is configured to support `PathLocationStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below : my example code

important `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }` in your route file like below added

**home.route.ts**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { HomeComponent } from './';

export const HomeRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const HOME_STATES = [
    ...HomeRoute
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(HOME_STATES, { useHash: true })
    ]
})
```

**home.component.html**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#Om" target="_self">Om statistikk.siu.no</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Vilkar" target="_self">Vilkår for bruk</a></li>
</ul>
<p>  
  <a name="Om" id="Om"></a>
  Om statistikk.siu.no Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</p>
<p>
  <a name="Vilkar" id="Vilkar"></a>
  Vilkar Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

Comment: It did not work. If i use blank in redirectTo property, then URl becomes http://localhost:4200/#/